# AngularJS Animations Swap lines in table

Tags: css, angularjs, html-table, ng-animate

I'm trying to put animation on my app. This one present a table with lines, each line can be modified/deleted or moved.
This is the trick, I can move items between lines in my table but I am not able to put animation (inversion, swapping) on this action.
I have created a Fiddle based on a post I have found about the subject but this one was with divs and not table. I have modified it to match my case.

=> The original Fiddle (works):
https://jsfiddle.net/2begw155/

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people" class="person">
   {{person.first}} {{person.last}} &nbsp;
   <button ng-click="personUp($index)">up</button>
   <button ng-click="personDown($index)">down</button>
   <button ng-click="personRemove($index)">remove</button>
</div>
```

=> The modified one with table (don't work):
   https://jsfiddle.net/d81dd0tk/6/

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people" class="person">
        <td>{{person.first}} {{person.last}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="personUp($index)" ng-hide="$index === 0">up</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="personDown($index)" ng-hide="$index === people.length-1">down</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="personRemove($index)">remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to keep a table>tr>td structure and no width/height because of UX design. If anyone have an idea, that would be great.

**Edit 28/07**: allways trying to make it work, successfully tested on Firefox ! So this is a pb of transitions with webkit...

**Edit 29/07**: creating new Fiddle, works on Firefox, no transition on Chrome. Not sure that it is a webkit issue because other transitions works and with -webkit that does not change anything. I read something about that chrome only apply transitions on properties that are defined. In my case .person does not have a top property but even if I set this property, it doesn't work at all.
=> new Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d81dd0tk/7/

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you should do but if you transform your tr in a block like

```
.person {
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
     display:block;
}
```

This should work but it doesn't keep the property of table-row... Maybe you have to specify a width for the td.

Hope this can help.